# How to tell cmake to load a library from a different path?

Tags: c++, cmake, package

On my Linux machine, I have the library `boost` installed in both directories:

```
/usr/lib # I used apt-get to install it
/usr/local/lib # I installed from source
```

When I use `find_package(Boost)`,  `cmake` always loads the library from the second path. How can I tell cmake to load the Boost variables from the first directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [`find_package`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.5/command/find_package.html) you can set hints, a suggestion to the find module on where to search for the package: so you should be able to find the required boost package with

```
find_package(Boost HINTS /usr/lib)
```

EDIT: but if you already know where your required boost version is you can also use `include_directories` and `link_directories`